# Remove extensions for Hack (HHVM) files on NGINX

Tags: url, nginx, url-rewriting

I haven't been using NGINX for a long time, but I know some things about URL rewriting from Apache, things that I could use here. I tried to remove the `.php` extension from my Hack files, here is what I did:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;

    rewrite ^/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)$ /$1.php last;
}
```

I see that `http://localhost/index` works (instead of `index.php`), but if I go to `http://localhost/ajax/blog/load` (instead of `load.php`), I get 404 error.

I've read [this](https://www.nullis.net/weblog/2011/05/nginx-rewrite-remove-file-extension/) article which explains what to do for this to work with PHP, but things are different for Hack.

What can I do to remove the `.php` / `.hh` extension from my URL, and perhaps add a trailing slash (but this is optional)?

Answer (score 0):

The `try_files` is throwing a `404` if the file does not exist, which is preventing the URI from being rewritten. Try making the `rewrite` the default path by moving it to a named location:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;
}
location @rewrite {
    rewrite /([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$ /$1.php;
}
```

EDIT: Changed regex from `^/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)$` to `/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$`

Comment: @Victor I notice that the original regex does not match paths with subdirectories. I have removed the anchor at the front so that only the last path element is tested, and removed the backslash (which is unnecessary to escape a hyphen placed first or last)